# Accessing two different workbooks from personal macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a personal macro which accesses two different workbooks.

Here is the updated code:

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet Set ws1 = Workbooks("Submittals").Worksheets("Sheet1") 
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet Set ws2 = Workbooks("Previous").Worksheets("Sheet1") 
    Dim num_rows_A As Integer
    Dim num_rows_B As Integer

    num_rows = ws1.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox ("Num rows in A = " & num_rows)

    num_rows_B = ws2.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox ("Num rows in B = " & num_rows_B)
End Sub
```

When I run the code, if A is active, then the MsgBox for A works, but for B I get this error:

> Run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

- If B is active, I get the error.
- If I comment out all three lines related to A, the MsgBox for B works fine.

Any idea what I can do to access both workbooks?

I do not understand what qualifying a range to a worksheet means.  Any suggestions of where I can go to read about this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are two "Range"-s, but only one of them is qualified with  " Workbooks("A").Worksheets("Sheet1")."   Each of the Range-s needs to be properly qualified,  A or B.  Just because the second one is inside parens does not mean that it inherits the outer qualification.

Comment: Look at [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) to shorten the code - as @donPablo said `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` needs to be qualified to the worksheet to.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked up qualifying an object, and tried adding this to my code, along with changing the references, but I still have the problem. : 
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Workbooks("Submittals").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Previous").Worksheets("Sheet1")      How do I qualify worksheets from two different workbooks?

Comment: @H.Watkins Please edit your fully updated code - there's a good chance that you're still not fully qualifying all your `Range`s.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still confused about how to qualify the range to the worksheet.  Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You still had 2 unqualified `Range`s in your updated code - I've fully qualified them for you below:

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Workbooks("Submittals").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Workbooks("Previous").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim num_rows_A As Integer
    Dim num_rows_B As Integer

    num_rows = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox ("Num rows in A = " & num_rows)

    num_rows_B = ws2.Range("A1", ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox ("Num rows in B = " & num_rows_B)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I finally understand what everyone was trying to tell me.  Blessings!

Comment: Please note that you cannot use `Integer` for row counting variables. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle and `.Count` returns a `Long`! Therefore both variables need to be of type `Long`. • Regardless I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.